# In Lucene, what is the accepted way to return an approximate result count without impacting performance?

Tags: lucene

I want my users' search results to include some idea of how many matches there were for a given search query.

However, after a bit of research and observation of my users' search logs, I've noticed a direct correlation between logged query speed and the number of total results and have determined that this is because I am accessing the `totalHits` property, which apparently has to iterate over the entire result set in order to return a value.

I would be happy to simply return an approximate value, maybe even just an order of magnitude indicating a rough idea of how many results are available, but I can't see if there's any good way to calculate this without noticeably affecting performance. I don't really want to just dump a seemingly-bottomless result set in front of the user without providing them any rough idea of how many results their search matched.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With boolean queries you can try to approximate:

- <s>`|A or B| / |D| = ((|A| / |D|) + (|B| / |D|)) / 2`</s>
- `|A and B| / |D| = (|A| / |D|) * (|B| / |D|)`

Where `A` and `B` are two terms, and `|D|` is the total number of documents. This is basically making an assumption of independence.

You can use the `rewrite` method to rewrite any query to a boolean query.

There isn't really a better way of doing this, but I've found that this assumption isn't too bad in practice. If you have a very small number of docs it might give bad answers though.

EDIT: as jpountz points out, my calculation for OR is wrong. Should be:

```
P(A U B) = 1 - P(~(AUB)) 
         = 1 - P((~A) & (~B))
         = 1 - P(~A)P(~B)
         = 1 - (1 - P(A))(1 - P(B))
         = 1 - (1 - P(A) - P(B) + P(A)P(B))
         = P(A) + P(B) - P(A)P(B)
```

Comment: There's something missing here... I think you must divide the left-hand side with |D| as well.

Comment: @Marko: You're absolutely right, my mistake. I'll update the answer.

Comment: Btw I was wandering about your approach... isn't independence a dangerous assumption for query terms, which often form a phrase? I think that in practice taking the most uncommon term as the measure gives you the upper bound and your metric gives the lower bound. The real hit count would be even lower only if the terms actually anti-correlated, which I take as very rare in practice.

Comment: @Xodarap Why are you dividing by 2 in the OR case?

Comment: @Marko: Anecdotally this works well for me, but it could be that my users are apathetic. Would be very interested in any data comparing these approaches.

Answer (score 2):

Recent versions of Lucene have a collector dedicated to computing counts called [TotalHitCountCollector](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/TotalHitCountCollector.html).

It is usually faster than other collectors because:

- [it accepts documents out of order](http://lucene.apache.org/core/old_versioned_docs/versions/3_5_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Collector.html#acceptsDocsOutOfOrder%28%29),
- it doesn't need to compute scores,
- it doesn't build the array of the top matches.

Answer (score 1):

First we should know what kind of query you want to do that for. For example, there is a very fast way to find out how many documents there are containing any concrete term (the term's *docFreq*). So, say you have a conjunction of three terms, you can approximate with the smallest of the three *docFreqs*.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding `totalHits`: this is just a value set by lucene after completing the search. Accessing the property does not do any extra work and certainly doesn't iterate all results.

Lucene always sets this (and knows how many results in total there are) when doing a search. It needs to do that in order to give you the requested top-N results (by score or sort field depending what you specified).

So actually the search is slow for certain situations.

Have you checked what kind of queries are slow?
The combination of slow and lots of results can indicate there are some sort of wildcard/fuzzy queries.

General information for improving search speed can be found at http://wiki.apache.org/lucene-java/ImproveSearchingSpeed

Based on your lucene-2.9.2 tag I would recommend first that you try upgrading to the latest version if possible and measure again. There were a lot of changes/improvements since 2.9.2